# Maintenance cost of unit tests which mock abstract classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

Mocking abstract classes seems appealing at first, however some change in the constructor of the abstract class can broke unit tests where the mock of the abstract class is used. So unit test isolation is not 100%. I mean no one can guarantee that the constructor of the abstract class is simple. ( I mean do not throw, do not call DB or weird things like that). I know that the constructor should be simple, but I cannot guarantee that it will stay simple all the time.

Our legacy code base is abstract class heavy, and I don't really like to mock abstract classes.
This is the main reason I prefer interfaces, or wrapper interfaces around abstract classes. Is  there a way to surround the call for the base class constructor? To be honest I have never ever created abstract class during TDD, but I cannot change the legacy part of our system.

I am biased to interfaces, but i am wondering that the issue I mentioned is real, or can be bypassed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do that with the Fakes framework.

Comment: How do you mock an abstract class? If I want to isolate a class `B` for testing, where `B : A`, for abstract `A`, how exactly do you mock out `A`? Insert something between `A` and `B`?

Comment: Imagine the classA is abstract class which injected through ctor to classB. Or classA is a simple method parameter for classB. Later on classA's ctor is changed, and my unit tests for classB will fail, due to exceptions from classA ctors. This means my tests are not 100% isolated.

Comment: So how does this problem differ from having to mock a non-abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

I would use interfaces over abstract classes as unless there's a good argument against it composition is preferable than inheritance.

But are you using a code productivity tool such as ReSharper or CodeRush? They allow you to refactor code including constructors efficiently which will save you hours in instances such as this.

Comment: sometimes u are not allowed to refactor. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you mention is absolutely real. Mocking an abstract class and using its constructor or one of its concrete methods in the test really amounts to testing the class under test *and* the abstract class. It's not really a unit test any more. Mocks are already fragile animals, this only gives them an additional reason to screw your tests.

I guess the solution is pretty much contained in your question - use interfaces. It's best if you can make your legacy abstract classes implement these interfaces directly, but you can also wrap them and depend on the wrapper's interface rather than on the abstract class.

Being "interface biased" might not be a bad idea when it comes to dependencies. Interfaces define a contract describing *what* operations are available on a collaborator. Abstract classes (not purely abstract ones, which are pretty useless compared to interfaces) describe *how* a family of classes behave when executing a particular operation. You don't want to depend on the how and be coupled to details, you want to be coupled to high level abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

As neoistheone commented, you can generate stubs from abstract classes with the Microsoft [Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#bkmk_partial_stubs) framework.